# stop service after execution

Tags: android, service, locationlistener

Hi I am writing program which fetches users current lattitude and longitude every 5 minutes using Alarmmanager and store the value in shared preferences.I want to run this search backgroun so iam using service.I want to stop the service after fetching the lattitude and longitude to avoid battery drain.This is my code

CurrentLocation.java

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CurrentLocation extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private Context mcontext;
    SharedPreferences shprefs;


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        this.mcontext=this;
        getlocation();

    }
    private void getlocation() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("evvterer", "mnbj");
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mcontext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        shprefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CurrentLocation.this);


        double latitude=location.getLatitude();
        Editor edit=shprefs.edit();
        edit.putString("Ltd", ""+latitude);
        edit.commit();

        double longitude=location.getLongitude();
        Editor edits=shprefs.edit();
        edits.putString("Lngtd", ""+longitude);
        edits.commit();
        LatLng loca=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }   
}
```

please help me
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use Broadcast receiver instead of service because broadcast receiver intent trigger when your condition meet  so use broadcast for fetches users current latitude and longitude every 5 minutes.:) from broadcast receiver your battery is not reduce very much as service do

Answer (score 0):

As you use returning null from onBind, you may be using startService() to start your CurrentLocation service. 
So when you are done with your CurrentLocation service, simpally call `stopService (Intent service)`

But if you have used bindService then you have to use unBindService().

To stop service at exact time, you can call a method in your activity at end of onLocationChanged() and from that method stop the service.

Or send a message to handler associated with your Activity to stop the service.

And add your code to start the service, so that it will help others to answer your question.